# Checking version of angular-cli that's installed?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Is there a way to check the specific version of `angular-cli` that's installed globally on my machine? I'm in a Windows environment.
`*npm -v* and *node -v*` only gives me the version of npm and node respectively, and I can't seem to find any commands with *ng*.

I'm trying to run a project that I'm working on, and it ran on an older version of angular-cli using npm. However, after installing other demo projects, my main project doesn't work anymore without uninstalling and reinstalling `angular-cli` at the specific version.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

angular cli can report its version when you run it with the version flag

```
ng --version
```

Comment: If you want to check out the versions of your global npm modules, you could also type something like `npm list -global --depth 0` to your terminal.

Comment: @fuma's answer will work even if you don't have Angular CLI installed. But it is recommended. Install instructions: http://ngcli.github.io

Comment: Downvoted since the OP specifically asks about the *global* installed package. @fuma's answer is correct

Comment: I use CMD on windows 10. When I run `npm list -global --depth 0` it does NOT show angular. But When I execute `ng --version` it shows me the result of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555618/3209523

Comment: If you try `ng --version` with angular cli 14, you will get _"Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands."_. Please use `ng version` instead.

Answer (score 97):

**Execute:**

```
ng v
```

or

```
ng --version
```

tell you the current angular cli version number

[image]

Comment: For me, only "ng v" and "ng --version" work. Although "ng -v" doesn't give me errors, it doesn't show the version, but shows a list of help commands.

Comment: @WilliamHou The same applies to me

Comment: for latest angular 14 only ng v works for me

Answer (score 21):

You can use `npm list -global` to list all the component versions currently installed on your system.

For viewing specific lists at different levels use `--depth`.

e.g:

```
npm list -global --depth 0
```

Answer (score 9):

**DON'T USE** `ng --version` because it provides a global system installed angular version.

Go to the `package.json` file, and check the `"@angular/core"` version. It is an **actual project version**.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to your folder path in cmd where your angular is installed and type 
`ng --version` it will show your angular version. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Im using Angular CLI: 15.0.5 , no need double dash, just use command

```
ng version
```

Answer (score 5):

**Simply run the following command :**

`ng v`

Answer (score 5):

Simply just enter any of below in the command line,

> `ng --version`    **OR**   `ng v`   **OR**   `ng -v`

The Output would be like,

[image: Screenshot]

Not only the Angular version but also the Node version is also mentioned there. I use Angular 6.

Answer (score 4):

In Command line we can check our installed ng version.

```
ng -v OR ng --version OR ng version
```

This will give you like this :

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___

   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.0.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
...
```

Comment: why are there `...` after the angular. Shouldn't it show the version number

Comment: Those `...` appears when you execute the command outside an angular application directory (global), if you execute the command within an angular application directory you will get the minimum angular version your angular application needs.

Answer (score 3):

`ng version` or `ng --version` or  `ng v` OR  `ng -v`

You can use this 4 commands to check the which version of angular-cli installed in your machine.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple run the following commands:**

```
ng --version
```

**OR**

```
 ng -v
```

Output on terminal:

```
      / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
            |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.15.0
OS: linux x64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find using CLI  `ng --version`

As I am using

angular-cli: **1.0.0-beta.28.3**

node: **6.10.1**

os: **darwin x64**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works with `ng version` and it does not work with `ng --version`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First try this : **ng version**

Else           : **ng --version**

Answer (score 0):

```
ng --version
```

[image: ng--version output]

Please take a  look at the above image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show **version on your page**, My version is **Angular 12**:

```
import { Component, VERSION} from '@angular/core';

then :

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'version-twelve';
  version = VERSION.full;
}

HTML:

<span>{{version}}</span>
```