# How to know If I'm using Angular 2 or 4 in Angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm currently using Angular cli version 1.1.0. I don't know If I am using angular 2 or angular 4. Can someone tell me how?

Comment: `ng v` lists the versions. The package.json file also has them.

Comment: It's already answered rather nicely here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017699/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-angular-im-using

Comment: @AhmedMasud that question is for angularjs and doesn't apply to angular CLI, JB Nizet's option will work but so will `ng -v` and `ng --version`. You can also use `ng --help` to find out more (although there is **quite a lot** there to sift through) The correct duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026895/checking-version-of-angular-cli-thats-installed (I realise that the correct answer is further down in the currently linked question, but it is primarily for angularjs)

Comment: Thanks man, Angular cli and angularjs was different. I thought it was the same thing he tag but anyway really help your references.